# How to create multiple helpers paths in Webpack config

Tags: webpack

Is there any way to create multiple helpers folders paths just like multiple entry in `webpack.config.js`? For example, there are two modules named `a` & `b`. For each modules, there are js and helpers folders; something like this:

```
└── module
    ├── a
    │   └── a-main.js
        └── helpers
            └── a1.js
            └── a2.js
    └── b
        └── b-main.js
        └── helpers
            └── b1.js
            └── b2.js
```

What will be the configuration for that?

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'module/a/a-main.js',
    'module/b/b-main.js',
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./js"),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "handlebars-loader",
          options: {helperDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, "./helpers")}
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: To clarify, you want webpack to create empty `helpers` folders within both the `a` and `b` folders?

Comment: No, there are already helpers folders for containing helpers functions inside each module. I've made an update to the diagram in my post for better understanding. I am able to write webpack config to take helpers function from one path only; I don't know how to pick helpers function from multiple paths.